# PySpark: How do I count number of spaces between in a string?

Tags: string, apache-spark, pyspark, count, substring

I know it is doable in Python, but is there any built-in function or *Like* or *IN* like facility? For instance, if the name column contains *`John    Doe`* then it should return *4* as space count.

Or should I create a UDF?

Comment: There are a couple of options, but a lot of it depends on what you are trying to do exactly. What if there are leading spaces? Trailing spaces? Multiple consecutive spaces?

If you just want to count the number of spaces, one option is to `split` by space, and use the length of the result minus 1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A couple of options:

```py
F.size(F.split('col_name', ' ')) - 1
```

```py
F.length(F.regexp_replace('col_name', '[^ ]+', ''))
```

Spark 3.4+

```py
F.expr("regexp_count(col_name, ' ')")
```